# Data table reload after ajax success response

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am using data table for listing. Now I want to filter some records on basis of few define filter.

I have done with filter using ajax I am creating a new response on basis of filter and replacing the response table of data table and everything is working fine.

But the problem is after done everything data table default search box and sorting is not working. See below code.

**Jquery code:**

```
//Search data from quarter 
$("body").delegate("#period","change",function(){
    var customer_id = $("#customer").val();
    var quarter = $("#period").val();
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    //if(quarter !=''){
        $("#ajax_loader_content").text("Please wait...");
        $("#ajax_loader").removeClass("hide");
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/appraisal-search') }}", // routing
            type: "POST",
            data: {_token: _token, customer_id: customer_id, quarter: quarter },
            success: function(res) {
                $("#ajax_loader").addClass("hide");
                if(res == 0){
                    $(".ajax-hide").addClass('hide');
                    $(".ajax-show").removeClass('hide');
                }else{
                    $(".ajax-hide").removeClass('hide');
                    $(".ajax-show").addClass('hide');
                    $("#data_table_tbody").html(res);
                    SITE.TableDropdownMenu();
                }
            },
            error: function(res) {
                console.log('Error:' + res);
            }
        });
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
public function searchAppraisal() {
    if(WebUsers::isBusinessAnalyst()){
        try {
            $customer = $this->_request->customer_id;
            $quarter = $this->_request->quarter;
            if (!empty($customer) || !empty($quarter)) {
                $data['appraisals'] = Appraisal::getSearchedAppraisals($customer, $quarter);
                if(count($data['appraisals'])>0){
                    echo view('analyst.appraisal.ajax_search_appraisal', $data);
                }else{
                    echo 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->_response['error'][] = $ex->getMessage();
            return response(Helpers::makeAjaxResponse(false, $this->_response));
        }
    }else{
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }
}
```

Is anyone face this before? How can I reload grid after success ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your dataTable, at the end of your `success` function, you need to redraw it with the new informations : `yourTable.draw();`

Comment: You mean I need to change something like :                {
                    $(".ajax-hide").removeClass('hide');
                    $(".ajax-show").addClass('hide');
                    $("#data_table_tbody").html(res);
                    dataTable.draw();
                    SITE.TableDropdownMenu();
                }